# Chrome extension: move downloaded file to input field

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, plugins

I am trying to migrate images with a small chrome extension i have built. the extension consists of 5 files:

popup.html - the plugin html document

```
 Has some html buttons
also has script link to my settings.js file that listens for the image downlaod button to be clicked and send a message to my content script : run.js to find the images
```

run.js - content script ( has access to the webpages DOM ).

```
This script recieves the message from run.js which then finds all the images names and image links i want to download. It puts them into an object and sends them via message to the backgorund script : bootstrap.js
```

bootstrap.js - runs the background page and has access to the chrome api.

```
var Downloads = [];
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse)
{
if(request.message.method == 'download'){
    for( var d = 0; d <= request.message.imageLinks.length; d++ ){
      chrome.downloads.download( {url: request.message.imageLinks[d],
             filename: request.message.imageName[d]}, function(id){

        });
          sendResponse('done');
    }
}
});
```

This all works fine and dandy. It loops through the images and downloads them.
What i need to be able to do now is: Take the images i just downloaded, and insert them into the file upload fields on the other website (which i have open in another tab) which have the same field names ect..
I see chrome has a

```
//Initiate dragging the downloaded file to another application. Call in a javascript ondragstart handler.
chrome.downloads.drag(integer downloadId)
```

At first i thought this might work since you can manually drag the downloaded image into the html file upload field without having to click and select the file. But i can't find any documentation / examples on it.

Does anyone know it is possible to get accomplish this with javascript / chrome api?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to access the content of the files you downloaded.

For that, you need to add a permission to `file://*`in your manifest file.
Then you can loop through your downloaded files with `chrome.downloads.search` for instance and get each file's path in the system (`DownloadItem.filename` property). For each file, make a GET XMLHttpRequest to the url `file://{filepath}` to get the file's content.

Once you have that content, you can convert it to a DataUrl and programmatically add the file to the FormData of your form (not the actual inputs though, just the FormData submitted in the end). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21422922/6065751) for this part.