# Accessing file data after download in Chrome...?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, html5-filesystem

I'm writing an extension that would ideally read files after they are downloaded (through the normal download process). Is that possible? I can get the filename through chrome.downloads operations, but I can't find ways of reading the actual bytes. I don't need to write or move them, just read.

Comment: Ideally you should not be able to read any file from the filesystem. That would be a security breach. If the file is being downloaded/ stored in the temporary FileSystem used by HTML5 then it is possible.

Comment: @user3613129 do you think I could somehow intercept a download to manage it with the fs api then?

Comment: I don't think so. Again if your extension would be able to intercept the download of a user, that would also be a security breach. FS API has a different use case. It is used to write/ read to/ from the Local filesystem, where the local filesystem means a temporary protected path created by the browser for these operations.
Please go through the FS API for more information.

Comment: @user3613129 Anything an extension can do can be seen as a "security breach". They have elevated privileges compared to the web code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I struggled with the exact same problem and finally found an easy workaround to read the content of downloaded files from a Chrome extension.

You just need to add a permission to `file://*`in your manifest file and once you have your file's path in the system (with [`chrome.downloads.search`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-search) in the `filename` property), make a GET XMLHttpRequest to the url `file://{filepath}`.

Comment: Uhm, I tried this in firefox and it doesn't seem to work. The code just stalls as soon as i do `xhr.open("GET", "file:///Users/myuser/Downloads/myexistingfile", false)`. It works fine when the url is remote, so the call is correct. Can you list your `permissions` array? Maybe FF is more restrictive than Chrome...

Comment: Nevermind, it's because local files do not have the same events as remote ones. By attaching to `onreadystatechange` things work as expected. Great!

Comment: .. or not. I still cannot read the actual data after the request is complete, the response is always empty in firefox. Disappointing.

Comment: You should not need more permissions than "downloads" and "file://*". As for the xhr request, be careful because what you retrieve is probably a Blob data. Here's my sample code for the request: 
        `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4) {
                file.blobData = this.response;
            }
        }
        xhr.open('GET', "file://" + file.filename);
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.send();`

Comment: I think it may be deliberately not supported in FireFox according to https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebExtensions/Filesystem#Accessing_file:.2F.2F_in_tabs_and_content_scripts

Comment: I've tried this and as many things as I can and am still getting an error "XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///Users/my_user/Downloads/downloaded_file' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy". I've given "permissions": ["downloads"], "host_permissions": ["file://*"], and "web_accessible_resources": [{"resources": ["file://*"],"matches": ["<all_urls>"]}], in my Manifest file, Tried opening Chrome with --allow-file-access-from-files flag, And turned off my chrome security settings (Momentarily), And nothing helps this CORS issue. Can anyone help me resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

No, the Downloads API does not provide a way to access the file contents.

The closest for interception would be WebRequest API, but at the moment that [doesn't allow response access](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=487422) either.

The most you can do is to catch a request with `webRequest`, cancel it and try to XHR it yourself, storing the result in some temporary place like the mentioned FileSystem API. This would be a terrible UX though (the original request fails inexplicably) and may not work in all cases (as XHR can't set all the headers to fully replicate a request).

Comment: If I initiated the download myself with a separate explicit action via XHR (i.e. Right-click-> "download with MyExtension"), would I then be able to prompt the user to save it in the standard Downloads folder somehow?

Comment: You would be able to invoke `chrome.downloads.download` afterwards

Answer (score 0):

WhiteFangs' solution worked for me. HOWEVER, I should add the caveat that the XMLHttpRequest using the file protocol only worked for me when I initiated it from the background script. I got errors when I tried it from a content script or from the javascript environment of my browser action.