# chrome extension to access content of downloaded files

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome extension and I'd like to have the extension:

1. Click on a link to initiate a file download
2. Once the download is complete, open and read the contents of the downloaded file
3. Do something with the contents of the file in JavaScript

I see that the [chrome.downloads](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads) API allows me to initiate the download and open the file, but is it possible for me to read the contents of the file (without writing native code)?

Comment: Nope, you'll have to use either a file input element that requires user interaction or redownload the file via XHR/fetch.

Comment: Or download in your extension via XHR/fetch, process it, then construct a blob and use createObjectURL to create a link element, then click it, which will initiate a download automatically. There might be an example of that somewhere.

Comment: @wOxxOm if I initiate a download automatically as you suggest can I get to the file's contents? I'm guessing no - you just suggested that so the file ends up in the user's downloads folder (which doesn't matter in my case). So if I want the content of the file I really have to XHR/fetch it myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm copying the answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44947814/6065751).

You just need to add a permission to `file://*`in your manifest file and once you have your file's path in the system (with [`chrome.downloads.search`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-search) in the `filename` property), make a GET XMLHttpRequest to the url `file://{filepath}`.

Comment: In Chrome this will work ONLY if the user explicitly allowed file access on extension's details page in chrome://extensions, which is disabled by default (except local unpacked extensions in development mode). Note that enabling file access for an extension exposes the entire file system (that's available for the current OS user) to the extension.