# I want to access downloaded file(csv file in my case) in google chrome extension and get content of that

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to google chrome extension in which I download one `csv` file and then get content of that `csv` file and move that `csv` file content to google spread sheet, but I am searching that is it possible that from chrome extension get the downloaded file?

Comment: It's not possible without writing an external utility and running it via nativeMessaging API. The workaround is to re-download the file using XMLHttpRequest/fetch.

Comment: How can we do that sir? you mean I have to re-download the file and the get content from it?

Comment: I read your comment on this issue as well (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41767585/chrome-extension-to-access-content-of-downloaded-files) but how to write a code?

Comment: fetch(url).then(r => r.text()).then(text => { /* use text here */ })

Comment: `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("GET", "url", false);
xhr.send();

var result = xhr.responseText;`  I think this works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself, here is

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("GET", "your_url_from_where _you_download", false);
xhr.send();

var result = xhr.responseText;

console.log(result)
```