# How to access a downloaded file from a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to access a downloaded file from a Chrome extension. When I use the method in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44947814/4878398) answer I am able to access to download when I load the unpacked Chrome extension from my file system. However, when I load the same Chrome extension from the Chrome webstore this does not work anymore. I get the following error:

> Failed to load file://PATHTOFILE: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

How can I get this to work when I load the Chrome extension from the Chrome webstore?

Comment: You need to enable the file access checkbox manually in chrome://extensions page for the entry from the store.

Comment: Wow that was easy. Is there a way to prompt the user to enable file access when the extension is installed or while the extension is used?

Comment: No, but you can make a GIF tutorial and show it to the user.

Comment: Good idea, thanks for the advice.

Comment: To assist the user you can open `'chrome://extensions/?id=' + chrome.runtime.id` using chrome.tabs.create.